# What is the meaning of 'too fond of fast horses'?

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions, idioms

In this sentence (from [*Noli Me Tangere*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=x0gxEAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Jose P. Rizal),

> The governor left his post; his successor had a reputation for justice, but, alas, did not stay in office for more than a few months; and his successor, in turn, was ***too fond of fast horses***.

what is the meaning of the final highlighted part?

Comment: Perhaps 'too fond of not-fast-enough horses' might be more accurate in some people's eyes.

Comment: [*There's always money for **fast cars, fast women,** and **fast horses***.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22fast+cars+fast+women+and+fast+horses%22) It's not an uncommon collocation in English.

Comment: I read it as a euphemism for "had an addiction to betting on horse races".

Answer (score 2):

There are a variety of examples in literature where the concept of ***fast horses*** relates to ***high living, or excess***. An example is of Kentucky being home to "beautiful women, fast horses and good whiskey": ([Source](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Kentucky_Bluegrass_Country/xqWr4n9DcGwC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=fast%20women%20and%20Fast%20horses&pg=PA6&printsec=frontcover))

Or characters referring to people spending more on fast horses (which could be considered somewhat frivolous) than they do on more important things:
([Trojan Horses](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Trojan_Horses/EZAfCgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22fast%20cars%20fast%20women%20and%20fast%20horses%22&pg=PT84&printsec=frontcover))

The complete phrase appears to be listing faults that the governors had, so considering these examples, if he was "too fond of fast horses" it suggests he put things of style and excitement before things of importance, which would not have made him a good governor. Although without further clarification, the sentence alone is open to interpretation as it could either be literal, or metaphorical.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the ELU. The [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) shows users how to provide a thorough answer.

Comment: It helps if you also do a bit of research to provide references for your explanations. Providing instances or definitions or explanations in dictionaries or on the web are encouraged here, rather than personal intuitions. Since you are new, I thought it might help to know.

Comment: It does help. Will look for specific references to phrases before making comments. Thanks.